# Iterate through DataTable to build a model for each ID

Tags: r, loops

I have a datatable that looks like this:

```
ID   Weeks  V1   V2   Sales
1      1    100  200    30
1      2    100  210    40
1      3    102  240    50
2      1    120  220    35
3      1    110  202    51
...
```

My aim is to predict sales in week 9 for every ID. Most IDs are filled with values from week 1-8, others just have one value.  This is basically what I want for every ID and not just ID 26:

```
train_ID26 = train[ID==26,]
test_ID26 = test[ID==26,]
model_ID26 = glm(Sales~ V1+V2,data = train_ID26)
test_ID26[,pred:= predict(model_ID26, newdata=test_ID26, type="response")]
```

I think this could be done with a for loop, but unfortunately, I am not familiar with those in R and couldn't figure out to build one. I also read that loops are often not the preferred choice in R.

Answer (score 2):

Consider `split` on both training and testing datasets then call your prediction with `Map` (wrapper to `mapply`) for elementwise iteration. Below assumes the same number of unique IDs are in both data tables.

```
# LIST OF DATA TABLES
train_list = data.table::split(train, by="ID")
test_list = data.table::split(test, by="ID")

# GENERALIZED PREDICTION FUNCTION
proc_model <- function(test_ID, train_ID) {
   model_ID <- glm(Sales~ V1+V2, data=train_ID)
   test_ID[,pred:= predict(model_ID, newdata=test_ID, type="response")]
}

# LIST OF PREDICTED DATA TABLES
pred_list <- Map(proc_model, train_list, test_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not scared of the `for loop` solution:

```
train_ID<- list()
test_ID <- list()
model_Id <- list()
for(id in train$ID){
  train_ID[[paste0("ID",id)]]=train[ID==id,]
  test_ID[[paste0("ID",id)]]=test[ID==id,]
  model_ID[[paste0("ID",id)]] = glm(Sales~ V1+V2,data = train_ID[[paste0("ID",id)]])
  test_ID[[paste0("ID",id)]]=test_id[[paste0("ID",id)]][,pred:= predict(model_ID[[paste0("ID",id)]], newdata= test_ID[[paste0("ID",id)]], type="response")]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LocoGris. This was indeed what I was looking for. However, got the following error message:
`Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
  numeric 'envir' arg not of length one

In addition: Warning messages:

1: In train_ID[paste0("ID", id)] <- train[ID == id, ] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

2: In test_ID[paste0("ID", id)] <- test[ID == id, ] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
`

Comment: Sorry, It should work now. Anyway, if you paste `dput(train)` and `dput(test)` or at least a significant part of them, we could replicate your problem so it is easier to answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks again! You had one typo in the last line at =test_ID, but it works now. The code will be running for a while. If I am stucked again afterwards I will use your hint and paste parts of the Dataset here.